# Rails migration, add new column using split - split() doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, split, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to add a max and min column to my model, based on a delimited string from another column:

`804025|1356906|2246774`

So the min should be: `804025`, and the max should be: `2246774`

I'm using this migration script:

```
def change
    add_column :mer14s, :rmax, :int
    add_column :mer14s, :rmin, :int
    Mer14.all.each do |mer|
        nums_a = []
        if mer.leading
            nums_a += mer.leading.split('|').map(&:to_i)
            puts mer.leading
            puts nums_a
        end
        if mer.lagging
            nums_a += mer.lagging.split('|').map(&:to_i)
        end
        if nums_a.length > 0
            mer.update_attributes(:rmax => nums_a.max)
            mer.update_attributes(:rmin => nums_a.min)
        end
    end
  end
```

However, the `split('|')` only returns the first element.

```
puts leading
puts num_a
```

**Output:**

```
804025|1356906|2246774
804025
```

I've confirmed it works in the `rails console` by using:

`Mer14.all[18].leading.split('|').map(&:to_i)`

**Output**
`[1189919, 3219748, 4010566]`

But it doesn't work in my migration file, nor does it work elsewhere (e.g. my models). Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: Where did you define `nums_a`?

Comment: It was defined in the first `if`, as leading should never be empty, but I've edited the code to deal with the case where `leading` is null.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `split` method didn't enjoy using a string inside rails. Instead a regex was used, so the original:

`nums_a += mer.leading.split('|').map(&:to_i)`

Becomes:

`nums_a += mer.leading.split(/\|/).map(&:to_i)`

Comment: glad you figured this out! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
a = "804025|1356906|2246774"
a.split('|').map(&:to_i).max
=> 2246774
a.split('|').map(&:to_i).min
=> 804025
```

Comment: Works in Ruby, but in rails I get the error `can't convert Fixnum into Array`

Comment: This obviously works, the problem in different place.

Comment: In rails, the split is producing a `Fixnum` not an `Array`, which suggests it's rails specific.